# OCaml option type in binary tree

Tags: ocaml

I have a few problems creating a tree size function with `type 'a option tree -> int`

```
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a
         | Fork of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

How would I create a t_opt_size function with type 'a option tree -> int?

I know I would have to use Some and the None operate.

I have this so far, but it's complicated to match with the option type.

```
let rec t_size (tr: 'a tree): int = 
    match tr with
    | Leaf _ -> 1
    | Fork (_, t1, t2) -> t_size t1 + t_size t2 + 1
```

Comment: What would `t_opt_size` do differently than `t_size`? Given that `t_size` works on *all* trees, it would work on trees of options just as well without needing to change anything.

Comment: For example, I could set a tree to let t5 : string option tree = Fork (Some "a", Leaf (Some "b"), Fork (Some "c", Leaf None, Leaf (Some "d"))). 
I need the function to hand option types

Comment: The function *does* hand that tree fine and will return 5 as expected.

Comment: I want the function to handle the type 'a option tree. I don't think you understand

Comment: Given that `'a option tree` is a subtype of `'a tree`, it already works. If you want to treat options different in that function, please tell us *how* different.

Answer (score 3):

I assume from your comments that you want a leaf that looks like `(Leaf None)` not to be counted in your tree size calculation.

Seems like the key is to split this:

```
| Leaf _ -> 1
```

Into two cases:

```
| Leaf None -> (* Left as exercise *)
| Leaf (Some _) -> (* Left as exercise *)
```

Since OCaml will take the first match, you can abbreviate this as follows if you like:

```
| Leaf None -> (* Left as exercise *)
| Leaf _ -> (* Left as exercise *)
```

You should make a similar change to the `Fork` case, though I have to say that `Fork (None, l, r)` doesn't really work for constructing a search tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generalize, you might need to write a generic tree walker which accepts a visitor function. I recommend you try to implement `fold_tree`, which accepts: (1) a fold function, taking some value, a tree and producing a new result (`'a -> 'b t -> 'c`), (2) an initial element of type `'a` as well as (3) a tree. Then, `fold_tree` returns a value of type `'c`.
Then, you should be able to call `fold_tree` with a function that skips over `None` leaves but otherwise increment the count like you did.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion but it might be suspicious to turn in such good code as the answer to a beginning assignment :-)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield It is a way to broaden the perspective: maybe OP will manage to implement that alone, or will at least know a little bit about what the professor is talking next time.

Comment: (You're absolutely right, I was just trying to work a humorous angle on it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to count all values in the tree as 1, but each depending on its contents, write a function that determines the count per value and use that:

```
let weight = function
    | _ -> 1 (* or anything else *)

let rec t_opt_size (tr: 'a tree): int = match tr with
    | Leaf v -> weight v
    | Fork (v, t1, t2) -> t_size t1 + t_size t2 + weight v
```

You even might want to generalise and pass the `weight` function as a parameter to `t_size` instead of writing different size functions that all use their own weighting.